# Request mapping is not exposed when application is started

Tags: spring-boot, http, spring-mvc

I have a controller class (@RestController) with one method to handle GET requests (@GetMapping). However, after the application is started, when I hit http://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings my request mapping is not there.

```
@RestController
public class SpringDemoController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

You can find the whole project here:
https://github.com/brunogcarneiro/spring-demo

The mappings result are: (http://localhost:8080/actuator/mappings)

```
[
   {
      "handler":"Actuator web endpoint 'mappings'",
      "predicate":"{GET [/actuator/mappings], produces [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json || application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}",
      "details":{...}
   },
   {
      "handler":"Actuator root web endpoint",
      "predicate":"{GET [/actuator], produces [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json || application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}",
      "details":{...}
   },
   {
      "handler":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)",
      "predicate":"{ [/error], produces [text/html]}",
      "details":{...}
   },
   {
      "handler":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)",
      "predicate":"{ [/error]}",
      "details":{...}
   },
   {
      "handler":"ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/webjars/]]",
      "predicate":"/webjars/**"
   },
   {
      "handler":"ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]",
      "predicate":"/**"
   }
]
```

Comment: Provided url to GitHub repo doesn't work, can you check if the repo is public?

Comment: Hello @Toni, it's public now. Can you check, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `SpringDemoController` is not located within the package or subpackages of the `@SpringBootApplication` class. Consequently, the component scanning does not detect your controller class.

You have two options:

- either move the `controller` package into the `springdemo` package
- or customize the base packages to scan as shown below.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example")
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm thrilled to announce that it is solved! :D